# "Field type <name> is not installed properly"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-field-type

SharePoint's telling me the following field type is 'not installed properly'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">InfoClass</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Choice</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">xyzInfoClass</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">xyzDescription</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">FALSE</Field>
    <Field Name="Sortable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="AllowBaseTypeRendering">FALSE</Field>
    <Field Name="Filterable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">SharePointProject1.CustomFieldType.InfoClass, SharePointProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16fde6e7376d101b</Field>
    <PropertySchema>
      <Fields>
      </Fields>
    </PropertySchema>
    <RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
      <Column HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
    </RenderPattern>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

I cut it down to what I pasted here and I still get the error. The namespace and assembly are correct and the dll is deployed to the GAC. Event receivers in the same project work, so I dont think it's the code. Having removed everything else I dont know what the problem could be

I'd ask in a proper sharepoint forum but I have IE7. so. this is the only site on the internet that works. and that includes the entire microsoft domain

Comment: I get the error when activating the custom fields feature from vs2010 deployment and from powershell, but not from the UI... meaning the deployment steps are going to be "go to each site and activate the fields feature manually b/c sharepoint *still* blows"

Comment: I'm getting the same error on 2013, works from the UI like you. Have you found a solution?